# showing Progress bar on long running for loops in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, jquery-ui-progressbar

I have a JSON array with around 2000 records and I need to build a table to display the data from these records.As it has large amount of data the processing may cause the browser to freeze.So I was asked to display a progress bar indicating the progress. Javascript being single threaded i have to use Setinterval to show progress.But the progress is not shown correctly in IE versions,depending on the number of records in the array.
Please help

```js
var g_arr = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'];

$("#btn").click(function() {

  var Loop = 1000;
  $("#tbl tbody td").remove();
  $("#divProgress").progressbar({
    value: 0
  });
  //window.setTimeout(function(){
  for (var i = 0; i < Loop; i++) {
    var TR = $("<tr>");
    $.each(g_arr, function(index, val) {
      var TD = $("<td>");
      TD.append(val);
      TR.append(TD);
    });
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      $("#divProgress").progressbar({
        value: (i / Loop) * 100
      });
    }, 3000);
    $("#tbl tbody").append(TR);

  }
  //},0);
});
```

```css
td,
th,
table {
  border-color: black;
  border-width: thin;
  border-style: solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<div id="divProgress"></div>
<div id="divBody">
  <input type="button" id="btn" value="Click Here" />
  <table id="tbl">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          Column1
        </th>
        <th>
          Column2
        </th>
        <th>
          Column3
        </th>
        <th>
          Column4
        </th>
        <th>
          Column5
        </th>
        <th>
          Column6
        </th>
        <th>
          Column7
        </th>
        <th>
          Column8
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

enter code here

Comment: I had the same problems with large amount of data, best solution for me was just simply display "Loading..." Instead of some animated loader, because they get stuck anyway

Comment: At first I thought of Placing a Loading gif...But it too gets stuck..anyways Tom your suggestion is appreciated,that would be my final try

Comment: you can also make it more dynamic, by adding percentage: "Loading... 10%" but that will get stuck too, so you will see jumps from 10 to 40 etc. But it does make it more dynamic

Comment: @Noval please check my update to support IE9 and below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple of things you are doing wrong:

- Avoid long `for` loops while doing DOM manipulations, which are very expensive. 
  Use [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) instead. RequestAnimationFrame
  basically instructs the browser that you wish to perform an animation
  (or some kind of computation) and requests that the browser call a
  specified function before the next repaint. In other words, its like
  a `for` loop, but each loop iteration runs only when the browser
  decides (when it can paint).
- You are creating 1000 unnecessary
  `$("#divProgress")` objects. Use cache. Create a single
  `$progressBar` and then use it 1000 times. Same problem with `$("#tbl tbody")` being created 1000 times.
- You are creating 1000
  progress bar plug-in instances. The way you are doing: 
  `$progressBar.progressbar({ value: (i / Loop) * 100})` is a
  constructor that creates a new progress bar instance with such value.
  Use the setter, not the constructor:
  `$progressBar.progressbar("value", (i / Loop) * 100)`.

```js
    var g_arr = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'];

    $("#btn").click(function() {

      var i = 0,
          Loop = 1000,
          $progressBar = $("#divProgress"),
          $body = $("#tbl tbody"),
          requestAnimationFrame =
              window.requestAnimationFrame ||
              window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
              window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
              window.msRequestAnimationFrame,
          
          doRequestFrame = function () {
              if (i++ < Loop) {
                  $progressBar.progressbar("value", (i / Loop) * 100);
                
                  var $newRow = $("<tr>");
                  $.each(g_arr, function(index, val) {
                    $newRow.append($("<td>").append(val));
                  });
                  $body.append($newRow);

                  if (requestAnimationFrame) {
                      // hey browser, please call again doRequestFrame() when you are idle (before repaint)
                      requestAnimationFrame(doRequestFrame);
                  } else {
                      setTimeout(doRequestFrame, 1);
                  }
              }
          };

      $("#tbl tbody td").remove();
      
      $progressBar.progressbar({
        value: 0
      });
      
      // hey browser, please call doRequestFrame() when you are idle (before repaint)
      requestAnimationFrame ? requestAnimationFrame(doRequestFrame) : doRequestFrame();
    });
```

```css
td,
th,
table {
  border-color: black;
  border-width: thin;
  border-style: solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<div id="divProgress"></div>
<div id="divBody">
  <input type="button" id="btn" value="Click Here" />
  <table id="tbl">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          Column1
        </th>
        <th>
          Column2
        </th>
        <th>
          Column3
        </th>
        <th>
          Column4
        </th>
        <th>
          Column5
        </th>
        <th>
          Column6
        </th>
        <th>
          Column7
        </th>
        <th>
          Column8
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**Support for older IE**

If `requestAnimationFrame` is not defined (as it happens for IE9 and below), I am calling the `doRequestFrame` manually.

Comment: I would NOT use requestAnimationFrame if you care at all about compatibility. All other points are spot on

Comment: hi Jose,anyways thankyou for pointing out the mistakes,I will rectify that..but coming back to progress issue , i saw that requestAnimationFrame would only work for IE 9 + versions

Comment: @Tom Please check my update. You should use graceful degradation, if `requestAnimationFrame` is not supported, then use it the conventional way.

Comment: Thanks Jose u just saved the day.I replaced the requestAnimationFrame inside the doRequestFrame  function with window.setTimeout(doRequestFrame,0); ....Now its working in all versions of IE

Comment: @Noval Great, but let the browser use requestAnimationFrame if it supports it, as you can see in my code sample.